# Remove Wordpress Comment Feed Link from header

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am talking about this line of code

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="example.com &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/comments/feed/" />
```

I have tried adding a remove action hook manually in template's functions.php

```
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links_extra', 3);
```

But it doesn't remove it.

I have tried wordpress [head cleaner plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/head-cleaner/) unfortunately it also couldn't remove it.

At last I have edited wp-includes/default-filters.php and commented out

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra',3);
```

My comment feed links are still there. I prefer functions.php modification or plugins other than modifying the core files.

I have tried disabling all the plugins and gone back to default theme but looks like the solution is not plugin or theme dependent. Unfortunately nothing works! I am using wordpress 3.2.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this one instead.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

Yours is for things like category feeds if I recall correctly.

Based on link coolsaint provided you could remove both and then explicitly add back in the posts feed. It isn't the most elegant, but it does mean you don't have to modify the core WP files.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'addBackPostFeed');
function addBackPostFeed() {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0 Feed" href="'.get_bloginfo('rss2_url').'" />'; 
}
```

Comment: the hook will remove my posts and comment feed both. I want only comment feed to be removed.

Comment: I think you are out of luck then. Looking at codex (line 1591) http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html - there is no callback and none of the args allow you to choose which of the two is displayed.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this page and gave me and workout and it worked http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-commentsfeed-link-and-link-to-wpme-from-twenty-ten?replies=5

Comment: @coolsaint - thank you for the link. I added it to my answer as a workaround.

Comment: Why are the priorities 2 and 3? (Not familiar with priorities enough to know)

Answer (score 11):

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

Adding this code to functions.php will remove all elements from your site that are related to RSS/Feeds.

Please Note: Before you remove this element from your site, make sure you know what this element is and why it is used. If you have lot of subscribers, then you may not want to delete this element.

Comment: I needed both lines of code to remove those links on my sites. So this answer was the best for me.

Comment: Wow. Works like a charm after everything failed.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but it appears that there are now filter hooks which can switch each feed independently (as you can see by examining the  [`feed_links`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/feed_links/#source) function code):

```
// add to functions.php
// display only main (not comments) feed links
function return_false() {
  return false;
}

add_filter('feed_links_show_comments_feed', 'return_false');
```

Comment: Since version 3.0 WordPress already have its own [`__return_false()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/) function, there is no need to define an additional one.